# How to use field rather than accessor from a closure in Groovy

Tags: groovy, closures, field, accessor

I have something like the following groovy class :

```
class Foo {
   private Map<String,String> bar = [:]

   Map<String, String> getBar() {
       return bar.asImmutable()
   }

   def doSomething(List<String> argValues){
     argValues.each {
        bar[it] = it
     }
   }
}
```

The doSomething method will fail, it seem, in the each closure, the bar property is use trough accessor, not the field. So it's immutable.

The question is "how can i use the field (not the accessor) within the closure ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `this.@bar[ it ] = it`

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you post it as answer to grant you the point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property accessor operator `@` like so:

```
this.@bar[ it ] = it
```